# DynamoDB .NET - Delete all items from a table

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-dynamodb, dml

I'm learning how to work with DynamoDB for .net and I have a doubt, Is there a correct way to delete all items from an existing table?, I mean, I don't want to delete the table, just empty it.
I've read about batch process but they don't help me much.

I have this

```
private string DeleteAllFromTable()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        try
        {

            var request = new BatchWriteItemRequest
            {
                RequestItems = new Dictionary<string, List<WriteRequest>> 
                { 
                    {
                        this.Tablename, new List<WriteRequest>
                        {
                            new WriteRequest
                            {
                                DeleteRequest = new DeleteRequest
                                {
                                    Key = new Dictionary<string,AttributeValue>()
                                    {
                                        { "Id", new AttributeValue { S = "a" } }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var response = this.DynamoDBClient.BatchWriteItem(request);

        }
        catch (AmazonDynamoDBException e)
        {

        }


        return result;
    }
```

But of course, that only delete the id that match with the value "a".

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend that you just delete the table and recreate it. From the DynamoDB [*Guidelines for Working with Tables* documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.TimeSeriesDataAccessPatterns):

> ...
>
> Deleting an entire table is significantly more efficient than removing
>   items one-by-one, which essentially doubles the write throughput as
>   you do as many delete operations as put operations.

Comment: So, I have to delete the table and immediately create it again with the same schema to can continue working. Thanks for your answer @Kobit-

Comment: @GameDev You do need to check the [table status](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteTable.html) and make sure you follow the guidelines. It might take a little bit of time, but it is a much better solution than and way faster than trying to empty out the table by deleting all the items. If this is the answer you are looking for, you should also accept it.

Comment: I think that this depends on the size of the table. A recreate can easily take a minute to complete and getting hold of the table schema seems like a total pain. I'm sure this makes sense on a huge table, but for testing I don't necessarily think it's always the best option.

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect. Deleting all the items is usually faster than drop/recreate unless the table has more than 100,000 items (YMMV depending on item size).

Answer (score 0):

Dropping a table and recreating it with indexes may result in application malfunctioning as drop/create table often takes much time which results in Resource in Deleting State Error