# Can we delete all data from dynamodb table using nodejs like truncate in mysql?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to delete all data from dynamodb table **using nodejs** package dynamo-client but no more result find from googling is there any way to complete this task ?

**I do not want to drop and recreate the table.**

I need nodejs code for this so I can customize it based on some additional requirements. Dropping the table would not accomplish that.

Comment: yes i am also facing same kind of issues please help !!!

Comment: This question should be reopened... I came here looking for a nodejs solution, but the dup is a Micro$oft .NET solution

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I could understand that It is more efficient delete and recreate

> Deleting an entire table is significantly more efficient than removing items one-by-one, which essentially doubles the write throughput as you do as many delete operations as put operations.

Here is the [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.TimeSeriesDataAccessPatterns) if you want to read more about

Here is the original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733640/dynamodb-net-delete-all-items-from-a-table) that I made with my problem

and thanks to @Kobit for the answer

Comment: But this is not a good way, Thanks for your answer !!!

Comment: I thought the same when I knew