# How to delete all the items from all tables of Amazon's dynamo db?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Just like backing up all the tables of dynamo db, i also want clear all the tables of my test environment after testing without deleting tables.
We used backup service such a way that we don't want schema structure or java object of table schema as below:

```java
Map<String, AttributeValue> exclusiveStartKey = null;

do {
    // Let the rate limiter wait until our desired throughput "recharges"
    rateLimiter.acquire(permitsToConsume);

    ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec().withReturnConsumedCapacity(ReturnConsumedCapacity.TOTAL)
            .withMaxResultSize(25);


    if(exclusiveStartKey!=null){
        KeyAttribute haskKey = getExclusiveStartHashKey(exclusiveStartKey, keySchema);
        KeyAttribute rangeKey = getExclusiveStartRangeKey(exclusiveStartKey, keySchema);
        if(rangeKey!=null){
            scanSpec.withExclusiveStartKey(haskKey, rangeKey);
        }else{
            scanSpec.withExclusiveStartKey(haskKey);
        }
    }

    Table table = dynamoDBInstance.getTable(tableName);
    ItemCollection<ScanOutcome> response = table.scan(scanSpec);
    StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
    Iterator<Item> iterator = response.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Item item = iterator.next();
        data.append(item.toJSON());
        data.append("\n");
    }

    logger.debug("Data read from table: {} ", data.toString());

    if(response.getLastLowLevelResult()!=null){
        exclusiveStartKey =  response.getLastLowLevelResult().getScanResult().getLastEvaluatedKey();
    }else{
        exclusiveStartKey = null;
    }

    // Account for the rest of the throughput we consumed, 
    // now that we know how much that scan request cost 
    if(response.getTotalConsumedCapacity()!=null){
        double consumedCapacity = response.getTotalConsumedCapacity().getCapacityUnits();
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug("Consumed capacity : " + consumedCapacity);
        }
        permitsToConsume = (int)(consumedCapacity - 1.0);
        if(permitsToConsume <= 0) {
            permitsToConsume = 1;
        }
    }

} while (exclusiveStartKey  != null);
```

is it possible to delete all items without knowing table schema? can we do it using **DeleteItemSpec**

Comment: You could do a `Scan` and then call `DeleteItem` for each entry, but it is much easier to just delete the tables and recreate them.

Comment: Hi @mkobit, if we recreate the tables then number of tables is increases and it will cost us.

Comment: I should have said before that it is easier, more efficient, and more cost-effective to delete the tables rather than delete each item. See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30733849/627727). Another possibility (since you mention testing) might be to make use of [DynamoDBLocal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html).

Comment: Thanks @mkobit, now i get a point, with same schema of table we can recreate it after deletion. Your link helps.

Comment: Here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733640/dynamodb-net-delete-all-items-from-a-table/30733849#30733849) already have a answer of this question by @mkobit